# growing Iframe auto scroll to bottom as it loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame that loads a script which outputs server actions. Is there a way to have the iFrame autoscroll to the bottom using javascript or jquery, to indicate the loading progress of the script?